# Generic functions in Swift

Tags: swift, function, class

I've been searching but most answers I've found are more complex than I can currently understand. If there is a tutorial out there I'd appreciate a link, but here is my question:

I have multiple functions that have the same mechanics and form, but call different classes. Right now, I repeat a lot of the same code and I imagine there's a shorter way to do this. Here is an example:

```
func nextQuestion() {

    switch analysisProgress {
    case 7:

        if questionProgress < ownershipQuestionList.list.count {
            questionLabel.fadeTransition(0.4)
            questionLabel.text = ownershipQuestionList.list[questionProgress].question
            definitionText.text = ownershipQuestionList.list[questionProgress].definitions
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNarrativeVC", sender: nil)
            }

    case 9:

        if questionProgress < discomfortQuestionList.list.count {
            questionLabel.fadeTransition(0.4)
            questionLabel.text = discomfortQuestionList.list[questionProgress].question
            definitionText.text = discomfortQuestionList.list[questionProgress].definitions
            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNarrativeVC", sender: nil)
            }

    case 10:

        if questionProgress < resourceQuestionList.list.count {
            questionLabel.fadeTransition(0.4)
            questionLabel.text = resourceQuestionList.list[questionProgress].question
            definitionText.text = resourceQuestionList.list[questionProgress].definitions
        } else {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToNarrativeVC", sender: nil)
        }

    default:
        ()
    }
```

What's the best way to handle these situations?

Comment: Show the declaration for the three different list variables in your code. And where does the `list` property come from and what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with generics. It seems to be merely a matter of refactoring to enforce DRY (don't repeat yourself).

- If the idea is that `ownershipQuestionList` and `discomfortQuestionList` and `resourceQuestionList` all need to have certain properties in common, then make them have the same class, or be subclasses of the same class, or be adopters of a common protocol.
- If they already do that, then just move the common code off into a local function and call it each time.

Comment: Thank you for your help Matt! Yes I think you're right in your first suggestion that it's not about the function, but how I structured the classes...